# Select2 remote source on dropdown field search term not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a city field, where on inlinedit call it loads ajax data on dropdown list. But when I typing a term it does not select the result with auto select. For example, If I typing "pabna" then it should select the auto select option with "pabna", now it only shows the underline with the result i.e on "pabna" it just show a underline on pabna word. I am trying to improve my code with the following data function.

```
$('#city_id').editable({
            type: 'select2',
            name: 'otmp_tx_user_details:city_id',
            pk:"userdetailid:<?php if($student_info->userdetailid) echo $student_info->userdetailid; else echo "0";?>",
                    select2: {
                                    ajax: {
                                    url: "<?php echo site_url()?>students/get_city_by_country",                                           
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: function (term, page) {
                                        return {
                                            term: term 
                                        };
                                    },
                                    results: function (data,page) {
                                            //alert(data);
                                            return {results: data};
                                            }
                                        }
                                },

            url: "<?php echo site_url();?>students/inlineedit",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
```

Please click here to see what I actually fetched. [enter link description here](http://nila.mobi/error.jpg)
Please check and help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Source2 documentation at the [website](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

"Select2 uses jQuery's $.ajax function to execute the remote call by default. An alternative transport function can be specified in the ajax settings, or an entirely custom implementation can be built by providing a custom query function instead of using the ajax helper."

My custom query (using a Backbone.js model and collection provider) is as follows:

```
query: function (query) {
    var data = {results: []};
    self.collection.each(function(model) {
        var s = "";
        if (model.get("name").indexOf(query.term) !== -1) {
            s += model.get("name");
            data.results.push({id: model.get("id"), text: s});
        }
    });
    query.callback(data);
}
```

As you can see, I just do a simple conditional check of the query.term (what is typed in the search box).

Comment: As per select 2 v4.0 "https://select2.org/configuration/options-api" this has been deprecated